# Is it right to try finding a vector where the dot product is zero in this problem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

In an assignment, I am given this problem:

> A blimp is held in place with two ropes. The wind is creating a force of 300 N on a bearing of 280° and one of the ropes is exerting a force of 250 N on a bearing of 170°
>
> What force is being exerted by the other rope?

If the winds force is $\vec W$, the known rope $\vec R_1$ and the other rope $\vec R_2$, then is it right to attempt finding a vector $\vec R_2 $ where $\vec W\cdot(\vec R_1+\vec R_2)=0$? Or is it the answer to the problem something else, if so: how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're overcomplicating it.

Since the blimp doesn't move we must have $\vec W+\vec R_1 + \vec R_2=0$. You know $\vec W$ and $\vec R_1$, so you can find $\vec R_2$ without doing things with products.

The real problem in the exercise is that your givens are expressed in polar coordinates, which makes adding/subtracting vectors cumbersome, so you'll probably want to convert them to Cartesian to start with. Or you may draw the parallellogram rule and use trigonometry if you're more comfortable with that.

---

(By the way, with a wind force of only 300 N, it must either be an extremely small blimp, or a *very* light breeze).

Comment: Oh yes, that does make a lot more sense. I've already converted the vectors, so now it only remains to find the components of $\vec R_2$ and calculate its force/magnitude. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I won't argue with the task text. I wonder though, doesn't it sound odd for the wind to blow at an angle of 280 degrees East of North?

Comment: @Threethumb: Why is that odd? That's how compass bearings are usually expressed.

Comment: Nevermind, I pictured 280 as being almost directly North, but I realize now it's almost directly West. Also, I found that the force of the other rope must be approximately 318.12 Newton. Is that right? I feel like I may have gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Threethumb: Doesn't sound clearly ridiculous, given the input numbers.